# Admin error while configuring django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i got this error while trying to get django admin running on my web app.

```
SyntaxError at /admin/
invalid syntax (admin.py, line 1)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (admin.py, line 1)
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
```

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python

Is there any solution for this?

I've tried googling but its a strange error.

The best part, there is no admin.py file in my web app.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove comments from `admin.py` make sure that you remove the leading spaces from that lines also.

Please check that file and if this will not solve the problem then give the context of `admin.py`

Comment: well i manage to work around the problem. But the issue is when i comment out the admin.autodiscover() the error goes away. However when i do some actions on my admin page, i will not be able to do it again the next time. So i need to insert that statement back in. but how do i work around it? Upon reinserting, the syntax error comes back again.

Comment: will you please provide the same `admin.py` which you are using?. You can also send me on my mail id.

Comment: from r2.models import Keyword

from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Keyword)

Comment: My admin.py is as follows:



from r2.models import Keyword
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Keyword)